# Integrating the Paho MQTT C Client Library in Eclipse IDE

Tags: c, mqtt, iot, paho

I would like to incorporate the [Paho MQTT C Client Library][1] into one of my C programmes. Due to my origins in EE, I find it challenging to complete this endeavour. However, my efforts and my problem are described below.

The objective is to use a username, password, and a C programme to subscribe to a particular MQTT topic. If this is accomplished, I will be able to complete the remaining tasks in C, such as storing the data to a.txt file and so on.

Since I have a background in electronics, my familiarity with compiling and making these kinds of complex projects function is limited, but I want to improve.

I am able to compile small applications with "make all" and use the resulting binary executable to run such software. I simply do, clean and make everything.

Nonetheless, the concept of compiling a library makes no logic to me. Why must I compile libraries in the first place? Typically, when I write C programmes, I include a library by utilising #include "library2.h". From this method, I am able to invoke library functions and complete tasks. Why can't we use Paho similarly? I do not comprehend why the Paho MQTT C library must be compiled. I want to know the technical justification for this.

Second, and most significantly, I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide me with step-by-step instructions on how to write a simple C programme that can subscribe to my MQTT server in order to print the messages published in that topic. I use Ubuntu 14.10 LTS.

I realise that this may be a very elementary question. I have sought answers to this query from other lab members and experimented with the example provided on [1].

When I attempt to do so, I am inundated with error messages, and I cannot seem to get this to function. Perhaps one of you can shed some light on the correct guiding steps to get my client working and also how to implement paho MQTT C into Eclipse IDE

I would greatly value your efforts in this matter. It would be very helpful.

I tried implementing into my Eclipse IDE but it is not getting compiled

Answer (score 0):

The Paho library must be compiled first because it has not been complied and packaged for Ubuntu, so there is no way to install the pre-compiled binaries for your system to just link against. The libraries you are used to using have to be compiled by somebody, in this case that step just hasn't happened.

We can't help solve the errors you are getting because you haven't shown them to us.

I will suggest not using Eclipse to try and compile the Paho library, it comes with a make file that will build and install (`make install`) it properly, you can update your include and library search paths for the project you wish to build to include the install location (which by default will be under `/usr/local/`)

Comment: But I cant be using Any other software other than eclipse as its my project oriented

Comment: It's not really using any other "software" it's just a case of running `sudo make install` in the Paho C directory